# what exactly is the Initialize Component method doing?

Tags: c#, initialization

In my project InitializeComponent (); method used several times. My Question is, what exactly is the Initialize Component method doing?

Comment: sounds like you could have done a simple MSDN google search for this as well as google C# for beginners doesn't sound like software development / coding is the right career path for you.. sorry

Comment: right click it and choose "Go to Definition", **Edit** (What about this is broad and unclear?..)

Answer (score 1):

if you look at your file in VS you can see a little "+" sign next to them and open that and the designer. there you will find the `InitializeComponent` method that start the controls you've put in your form

the `InitializeComponent` is generated by the VS according to the control you've put in your form when designed the form

for example if my form is look like this:

[image]

then `InitializeComponent` will be:

```
  private void InitializeComponent()
  {
     this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
     this.SuspendLayout();
     // 
     // button1
     // 
     this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(85, 36);
     this.button1.Name = "button1";
     this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
     this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
     this.button1.Text = "MY BTN";
     this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
     // 
     // Form1
     // 
     this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
     this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
     this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
     this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
     this.Name = "Form1";
     this.Text = "Form1";
     this.ResumeLayout(false);

  }
```